# Вывод строки между двумя другими строками

Tags: php, mysql

Есть многоуровневое выпадающее меню, мне нужно вставить строку между двумя другими строками. Например, есть такой вывод и мне нужно вставить Автобус между Троллейбусом и Трамваем. Подскажите, как это реализовать на MySQL и PHP на любом уровне вложенности?

```
Первый
Второй ->
         Тойота
         Ауди ->
                Троллейбус
                Трамвай
         Акура
```

Comment: Зависит от структуры хранения дерева.

Comment: В таблице есть колонки: id, value, path, id_parent. Меню выводится через рекурсию на PHP.

Comment: может какие колонки добавить и по ним сортировать?

Comment: *В таблице есть колонки: id, value, path, id_parent.* Структура **НЕ** предусматривает хранения порядка вывода. Меняйте структуру. *может какие колонки добавить* Формально - можно. Но правильнее - почитать теорию по хранению деревьев в БД, и на основании прочитанного и имеющихся требований к выводу и операциям выбрать структуру хранения.